# How to create a simple Account management using python?

Tags: python

I would like to expand my account management by allowing customers to open a new account with their name and account balance. The account number should be generated automatically (consecutive).

I would also like to add the following:

- It should not be possible to overdraw the account.
- It should no longer be possible to deposit or withdraw a negative amount.

Unfortunately I can't get any further here.

This is how my account.txt file looks like:

```
1, Max Mustermann, 1000.0
2, Nora Mustermann, 790.0
3, Tomas Mustermann, 400.0
```

This my coding:

```
data = {}
with open("Account.txt") as f:
    print("Which account do you want to use?")
    for folder in f:
        list = folder.split(",")
        account_number = int(list[0])
        name = list[1]
        credit = list[2]
        data[account_number] = list[1:]
        print(f" [{account_number}] {name}")

print(" [+]  Create new account")
print(" [0]  End")

input_first = int(input(" Your input: "))

if input_first == 0:
    print("Thank you and see you again")
    exit()
elif input_first == '+':
    print("new account")
    #From here I get no further, how to use "+" in a input?
```

```
while input_first in data:
    credit2 = data[input_first][1]
    name2 = data[input_first][0]

    with open('Account.txt', 'r') as file:
        filedata = file.read()

    print("\n[1] Deposit\n[2] Withdraw\n")
    execution = int(input(" Your Input: "))

    #How can I overdraw my account and make it impossible to deposit or withdraw a negative amount?
    if execution == 1:
        deposit = float(input(" Your deposit: "))
        amount_e = float(credit2) + float(deposit)
        print(f" The account balance of account{name2} is {amount_e:.2f} $")
        filedata = filedata.replace(str(credit2), str(amount_e) + '\n')

    elif execution == 2:
        payout = float(input(" Your pay out: "))
        amount_a = float(credit2) - float(payout)
        filedata = filedata.replace(str(credit2), str(amount_a) + '\n')
        print(f" The account balance of account{name2} is {amount_a:.2f} $")

    with open('Account.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't store user data in a txt file. It is not encrypted and it's prominent to data getting stolen. Might wanna look into a database like [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) in case you want to store it locally or [MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp) in case you want it to be stored in a server (I recommend SQlite to start off with). It is also way more intuitive to add, edit and remove elements this way than editing a plain txt file.

Regarding the negative values it's pretty easy. You just check if the value is not negative like this:

```
if execution == 1:
    deposit = 0
    #Don't proceed until a correct value is entered 
    while deposit < 0:
        try:
            deposit = float(input(" Your deposit: "))
        except TypeError:
            #For handling an error if a non-numeric value is entered
            pass
    amount_e = float(credit2) + float(deposit)
    print(f" The account balance of account{name2} is {amount_e:.2f} $")
    filedata = filedata.replace(str(credit2), str(amount_e) + '\n')
```

To stop a user from withdrawing a value higher than what's currently in its account you just check if the withdrawn value is bigger than the account's.

```
elif execution == 2:
    payout = 0
    #Keep asking for a value until the payout is less than the credit
    while payout > credit2:
        payout = float(input(" Your pay out: "))
        amount_a = float(credit2) - float(payout)
        # Print a message telling the user the reason
        if amount_a < 0:
           print("You don't have that much money in your account.")

    filedata = filedata.replace(str(credit2), str(amount_a) + '\n')
    print(f" The account balance of account{name2} is {amount_a:.2f} $")
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I check that the account is not overdrawn? So (1) the amount to be paid out must not be negative, (2) the amount to be paid out must be less than the amount in the account and (3) if the amount in the account is already negative, it must not be overdrawn (so I will include a print method like `prin("Your balance is in a negative range. Please deposit money first")`.

Comment: @virat Edited my response with the answer